# How can I redirect a not logged in person to the index page?

Tags: php

I would like a person who is not logged in be redirected to the index page.

on my onlymembers.php I put this code:

```
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 
echo "you are not logged in";
header("Location: index.php");
}
```

It is printing out "you are not logged in" which indicates that the login check is working. But I will not be redirected to the index page. Do you know why?

---

Update:

I used this code now and it is working:

```
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 
header("Location: index.php"); 
}
```

I have actually NO idea why. I just removed some whitespaces :-/

---

Update again: I know now the problem: I just removed the whitespace infront my `<?php` at the beginning of my page....

Comment: remove echo and see.. whether you are redirecting or  not ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php No output before headers

Comment: Don't use any echo return before header

Comment: is their any code on this page ? If yes, please share

Comment: yes there is a lot of code, I cannot share all of it

Comment: The reason it's failing is as @DanishEnam and @MichaelKunst says, the cause is that `header('Location;<URL>');` cannot have any "browser" visible output before it, if you have any error reporting turned on you'd see a error with "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .... "

Comment: don't share man.. but please can you remove 'echo' before header and see..

Comment: @DanishEnam: raveenanigam asked me to share

Comment: I removed the 'echo' but still no redirecting

Comment: Place `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your code, just below the `<?php` tag and then paste in the errors you are getting here. (Edit your question and post the errors there, **DO NOT** post them in the comments).

Comment: put  ob_start()  as the first and  ob_flush()  as last line of your code.

Comment: @Epodax I placed the error message, but still nothing happens when I lot the page

Comment: where you placed error message ?

Comment: @Epodax: Unfortunaltey not :(

Comment: <?
error_reporting(E_All);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 
header("Location: index.php");
EXIT;
} 
//Uncomment All Code
?>

Comment: Yes I had html code before it. But I deleted now all code. It is now only 
`<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);

session_start();





if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 

header("Location: index.php");

} 

`

Comment: But still no error message

Comment: place <? ob_start(); php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); session_start(); if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header("Location: index.php"); ob_flush(); }

Comment: @6339  I placed it and get a white page

Comment: @Epodax I replaced it and get still a white page

Comment: Remove the `ob_flush();` part and `ob_start();` - It sounds like you are getting some serious errors that aren't getting displayed as they should, are you on a shared host?

Comment: @Epodax without op_flush and ob_start I see my page again, but no redirecting (no not a shared host)

Comment: place ob_start(); just before header("Location: index.php");

Comment: @6339  placed ob_start before header.., I see my page but no redirecting

Comment: So, just to be sure, place `<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

header("Location: index.php");
die();` as the first thing on your page, if it doesn't redirect then it's not your code that is failing

Comment: I updated my answer, it is working now

Comment: Glad to see it's working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't send the content of a page before using an HTTP redirection (you should have a PHP error like "headers already sent" with your code). You either have to redirect using javascript or remove the "echo" :

```
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wrote the code like you suggested, but still it is not redirecting. How can I make the "headers already sent" error message?

Comment: Jarla, you need to make sure your check happens before any echos. If you do as you have shown, and you look at the logs (or increase your log level), you'll see the "headers already sent" message

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send an HTTP header after you've sent a visual output to the user. You could instead use an header with a refresh condition that will allow you to send an output to the user.

```
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 
header("Refresh: 5; url=./index.php");
//after 5 seconds the user gets redirected. To change the period of time just change the number after "Refresh"
echo "you are not logged in";
exit();
}
```

**P.S.** Is always suggested that you use an *exit()* function (like I did) when you want force redirect an user for security prouposes.

You could also put a variable on the redirect link and then parse it on index.php to display a message, like this...

**Redirect**

```
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 
$msg = "you are not logged in";
    header("Location: index.php?reply=$msg");
exit();
    }
```

**Additional index.php code**

```
if(!empty($_GET['reply'])) {
$reply = $_GET['reply'];
}
```

Then you have the *$reply* variable that contain the message you can display in your index.

Comment: I tried the first code you suggested, but I get an empty page with the message: you are not logged in. No redirection

Comment: Try to change the path of the url from "index.php" to "./index.php". I've also edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

there with location redirect not working then you may use javascript for this.

```
<script>
 window.location = "http://www.redirecturl.com/"
</script>
```

Comment: but is it more secure then header(location:...) ?

Comment: `header('Location:...');` is not client side, although I cannot tell you whether it's "secure" as I don't know, but I'm fairly positive that it is more secure.

Comment: you mean javascript is more secure?

Comment: No, the `header('Location'); ` is more secure, although I'm not certain.

Comment: @epodax, how is that more secure? You still ends up with the same result,. The reason you should avoid JavaScript is in case the user has it turned off

Comment: @JuanMendes Because the JavaScript can be manipulated by the user without the server having a say about it, a `header('Location:  index.php);` is static, and they can't change the URL, although I'm not sure if one can alter the headers after they are sent from the server. But again, I'm far from certain.

Comment: @epodax but the JavaScript could be run by the client anyway. The problem is when you generate JavaScript and you have unsanitized input, it could run with the user's credentials. I don't see any risk here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the if statement above the header file include.
2. ob_start() at the top of the script to buffer the output.

   ```
   if(!$user->is_logged_in()){    
       echo "you are not logged in";    
       ob_start();    
       header("Location: index.php");    
   }
   ```

OR

```
<script>                
    var url = "http://yoururl.com";    
    window.location.href = url;
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

[Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function should be used before html tag.

Example:

```
<html>
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```